# How to bring a React Native (Expo) app to the foreground from a background running task?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, background-process

I have a task running in the **background** using [expo-task-manager](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager), I want the app to open itself to the foreground when a certain condition is met, something similar to what happens when you receive an ordinary phone call or when an alarm is ringing. Something like this:

```
TaskManager.defineTask(MY_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (myConditionIsTrue) {
  //Bring the app to the foreground
  }
});
```

Basically, I want to do exactly what [this package](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app) does but unfortunately, it does not work with expo-managed apps and there is no other alternative third-party package. Does anyone know how I can achieve this behavior with Expo?