# How to add native code to React Native (Expo)

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, expo

I want to bring my expo app to the foreground from a background running task, the only third-party package I found on the internet that can do this is [react-native-invoke-app](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app) but it does not work with expo managed apps.

There are three ways I think I can do this but I do not know how to implement any of them:

1. How can I make this package compatible with expo by utilizing expo [config plugin](https://github.com/expo/config-plugins)?
2. How can I copy their native java code that involves bringing the app to the foreground into my expo app? and perhaps build a  [custom dev clients](https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8)
3. Is there any other method that I can use to bring an expo app to the foreground from a background running task? please see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72871344/how-to-bring-a-react-native-expo-app-to-the-foreground-from-a-background-runni) on this matter

I will appreciate any form of assistance

Answer (score 0):

What's your use-case? A bit part of the answer depends on what you're trying to do.

It looks like the react-native-invoke-app package works through push notifications, so I would try making use of push notifications. For example, you could schedule repeating notifications with this package: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-notifications

Or set up Firebase to send the push notifications based on some server logic, cloud functions, or API requests (which you could trigger with react-native-background-fetch).

You could also make use of a deep link, but it depends on your use case.

As far as I know, there's no way to force an app into the foreground without a push notification or a deep link.

Comment: I tried that but I still do not know how to bring the app to the foreground once the notification is received, please have a look at this new question I have just posted based on your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876431/how-to-bring-a-react-nativeexpo-app-to-the-foreground-when-user-recieves-a-not

Comment: Ah yes, I see. What you're describing is not possible, Apple would never allow it. What is your use-case (what does your app do)? In the other post you mention phone calls as an example, I believe there are separate APIs for that kind of thing.

Comment: Alright, to be more specific, I am building a ride-sharing app, I want to make sure that the driver never misses a ride so if there is a ride request for him and his app is in the background, I would like to urgently bring it to the foreground for his attention. I do not want to use ordinary notifications because the notification may get lost amongst other apps notifications

Comment: That makes sense. I believe rideshare apps incentivize drivers to respond to push notifications, downgrading their accounts if their response rate is too low. You could also use text or phone calls via a service like Twilio. If a driver leaves the app open, then you can use in-app notifications. I can't think of any other options...